# How to make a shockwave?

Tags: animation, workflow

How would I make a shockwave for an intro like [this one](https://youtu.be/t3LFMTNmxMc?t=3) at 0:04

Comment: You your question may be to broad to easily answer. From the videos those look like basic smoothed geometric shapes animated scaling up. The text also seems to me a copy of the text mesh animated scaling up, or perhaps using a solidify modifier. The material seems to uses some sort of Fresnel node to control transparency and give it a host.like appearence.